# How do I model data accumulation in an inheritance tree in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, tree, modeling

I'm not sure if my question is phrased correctly, but what I am trying to understand is the best way to model data that "accumulates" in an aggregated member variable in a tree of classes in C++. That is, each derived class *adds* some data to the member, inheriting some initial data from its parent.

For example, say I have a "description" string, which has a one or more sentences that are common to all classes in the tree, zero or more sentences that are common to various branches of the tree and zero or more sentences that are unique to specific leaf nodes.

What is the best way to model this in C++?

The most obvious way seems to be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        appendDesc("base description\n");
    }

    void printDesc (void) {
        std::cout << description;
    }

protected:
    void appendDesc (std::string description) {
        this->description.append(description);
    }

private:
    std::string description;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B() {
            appendDesc("extra description\n");
        }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    B b;
    b.printDesc(); // prints "accumulated" description
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using strings here as an example, but the principle applies to anything that needs to "accumulate" on an aggregated member through a tree of classes.

So, is the best way to have an `append()` method in the base class and make derived classes call it in their constructor, or is there a better way? Are there any downsides to the approach described above?

Comment: You could make the extra description a constructor parameter. Apart from new description, what else do the child classes do?

Comment: @NeilKirk In my actual use case, the child classes implement various machine learning algorithms, so they have common methods like `add()`, `train()`, `classify()` etc, but I was just curious about the general principle. `B() : A (desc)` does seem an improvement.

Comment: If your inheritance model is sufficiently far from the default C++ inheritance model, consider not using the C++ inheritance model for your inheritance model.  C++ doesn't have an accumulated property like you describe.  But a custom written Class/Instance pattern can easily have it.  A `Class` is something that can produce `Instances`.  `Class`es have inheritance relationships and methods, which operate on `Instance`s.  A child `Class` can override parent instances, and `Instance`s produced by the child `Class` are valid instances of the parent `Class`.

Comment: @Yakk I don't really follow. Would you care to provide an answer that illustrates the alternative inheritance model you describe with a code example?

Comment: @JamieBullock not really.  Look into how C programmers build "manual" object-oriented systems (with virtual dispatch and everything), or how lua objects work.  Then maybe wrap it in some syntactic sugar.  It is far from trivial, and may not be worth it if the only thing you want is that one difference.